# Trying to add NVIDIA packages on Yocto

Tags: nvidia, yocto, nvidia-jetson, yocto-recipe, jetson-xavier

By building the Yocto image I encountered this issue during populating Yocto SDK. Do somebody have any idea where and how to fix it?

But i'm getting the following error:

ERROR: python3-3.8.14-r0 do_package: Error executing a python function in exec_func_python() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_func_python() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: 
0001:
*** 0002:do_package(d)
0003:
File: '/home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/poky/meta/classes/package.bbclass', lineno: 2306, function: do_package
2302:    # Setup PKGD (from D)
2303:    ###########################################################################
2304:
2305:    for f in (d.getVar('PACKAGEBUILDPKGD') or '').split():
*** 2306:        bb.build.exec_func(f, d)
2307:
2308:    ###########################################################################
2309:    # Split up PKGD into PKGDEST
2310:    ###########################################################################
File: '/home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 192, function: exec_func
0188:    flags = d.getVarFlags(func)
0189:    cleandirs = flags.get('cleandirs') if flags else None
0190:    if cleandirs:
0191:        for cdir in d.expand(cleandirs).split():
*** 0192:            bb.utils.remove(cdir, True)
0193:            bb.utils.mkdirhier(cdir)
0194:
0195:    if flags and dirs is None:
0196:        dirs = flags.get('dirs')
File: '/home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/utils.py', lineno: 710, function: remove
0706:        # shutil.rmtree(name) would be ideal but its too slow
0707:        cmd = []
0708:        if ionice:
0709:            cmd = ['ionice', '-c', '3']
*** 0710:        subprocess.check_call(cmd + ['rm', '-rf'] + glob.glob(path))
0711:        return
0712:    for name in glob.glob(path):
0713:        try:
0714:            os.unlink(name)
File: '/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py', lineno: 364, function: check_call
0360:    if retcode:
0361:        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
0362:        if cmd is None:
0363:            cmd = popenargs[0]
*** 0364:        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
0365:    return 0
0366:
0367:
0368:def check_output(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
Exception: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rm', '-rf', '/home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3/3.8.14-r0/package']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3/3.8.14-r0/temp/log.do_package.282323
ERROR: Task (/home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.8.14.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4482 tasks of which 4473 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
/home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.8.14.bb:do_package
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

Please let me know any solution for this error

Comment: The error looks to be complaining about a python package, not NVIDIA.  I'd start by checking out what the logfile says:
 /home/vkchlt0732/yocto-tegra5/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3/3.8.14-r0/temp/log.do_package.282323

Comment: Run the below commands to rectify the errors. 
bitbake -c cleanall python3
bitbake python3